# Button Onclick function is not saving record to database

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring, jsp

Respected Friends,
I have problem with the ONCLICK button problem.
I have written Code for saving form to the database.

There are 2 Buttons in the picture:

- **Save** button           (type="submit")
- **Save and New** button   (type="button")

Save one is perfectly very fine. saving record on the database as "submit type" is used.
But when it comes to the *save & new*  its  not saving record to the database.

Please can anyone let me know what would be the problem with it.

***Please find the coding below:***

```
 <div class="btn-lg pull-right">
    <tr>                                    
<td><input type="button" class="primarybtn" value="Save" name="save" onclick="SaveEntity();"/></td>                                 
<td><input type="button" class="newwhitebtn" value="Save and New" name="saveAndNew" onclick="SaveEntity();"/></input> </td>
<td><input type="button" class="cancelbtn" value="Cancel"></td>
                                </tr>
                            </div>
```

***Script Code:***

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
  function SaveEntity() {   
    alert("Check Save");
      //    get the form values      
        $.ajax({
            url :"/leadstatus_creation",
            type : "POST",      
            contentType: "application/json",
            data : $('#frmCreateEntity').serialize(),
            success : function(data) { 
            if(data != null && data !='')
                {               
                    $('#txtleadname').val(data); 
                }               
            },   
            error : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
                alert(textStatus);
                alert("Lead Name Status:"+$('#txtleadname').val());
            } 
        });
    }
  </script>
```

> Please can anyone help me regarding this issue.

***ANSWER:***

> ***Just instead of using  tag we can use  tag Than its surely works.***

```
    <td><button class="primarybtn" name="save" onclick="SaveEntity();"/>Save</button></td>
    <td><button class="newwhitebtn"  name="saveandnew" onclick="SaveEntity();"/>Save and New</button></td>
    <td><button class="cancelbtn"/>Cancel</button></td>
```

Thank You All for support. . :-)

Comment: Why you are using two different types ? try to make button (type="submit") as well for second one and it will work.

Comment: No brother! There is big diffrence between its function. Save- On click of it -it takes to the VIEW. Save & New button will take to the New Form. Also there will be one more button (Skip) For those purpose i will need to use Type="button".. Please let me know if there is some solution for it.

Comment: Make a second JS Function, you can't accomplish it with only this one

Comment: But how  this JS function working for type="submit" but not for Onclick? How the second Js function would be? What kind of code it will content brother?

Answer (score 1):

The second one

```
<td><input type="button" class="newwhitebtn" id="frmCreateEntity" value="Save and New" name="saveAndNew" onclick="SaveEntity();"/></input> </td>
```

In this also you gave the same **id** of **frmCreateEntity** as in the first one,
That is why when the function is called

```
            data : $('#frmCreateEntity').serialize(),
```

The above code parses the DOM for the id, and it when it matches it gets the content of this

`<td><input type="submit" class="primarybtn" value="Save" id="frmCreateEntity" name="save" onclick="SaveEntity();"/></td>`

This is the reason it is not saving,
As the document parser does not know for how many elements you have defined with same **id** as **frmCreateEntity**, and it stops its search when it finds that same id in the first element with **ID** **frmCreateEntity**.
Try to implement with different id in both the input elements, 
It will definitely work,

Also i have added a workaround for your clarification, and getting data in that function for saving it into your database.
**Check this Code and run here,**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Sample styled page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="btn-lg pull-right">
       <td id="td_1">
         FIRST
         <input type="button" class="primarybtn" value="Save" name="save" id="id_1" onclick="SaveEntity(this);"/>
       </td>
       <td id="td_2">
         SECOND
         <input type="button" class="newwhitebtn" value="Save and New" name="saveAndNew" id="id_2" onclick="SaveEntity(this);"/></input>
       </td>
       <!-- <td><input type="button" class="cancelbtn" value="Cancel"></td> -->
    </div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  </body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
function SaveEntity(event) {
 var obj = document.getElementById(event.id).previousSibling;
 obj.trim;
 console.log(obj.wholeText);
    //  $.ajax({
    //      url :"/leadstatus_creation",
    //      type : "POST",
    //      contentType: "application/json",
    //      data : obj,
    //      success : function(data) {
    //      if(data != null && data !='')
    //          {
    //              $('#txtleadname').val(data);
    //          }
    //      },
    //      error : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    //          alert(textStatus);
    //          alert("Lead Name Status:"+$('#txtleadname').val());
    //      }
    //  });
 }
</script>
</html>
```

Now you can get both the values from both buttons event with **different** **id** .
Also here is the screenshot of the output : [image: Screenshot]

Hope it helps,

Thank You

Re-Edited:

*View as :*

```
<td><input type="button" class="newwhitebtn" id="frmCreateEntity" value="Save and New" name="saveAndNew" onclick="SaveEntity(this);"/></input> </td>
```

Comment: Thank you so much Bro Shohil . So i will need to serialize the Form again with different ID? Is there not an another way brother?

Comment: Brother! Even If i rename the type="submit" as type="button"  Its does not allows to Submit the form.

Comment: Please can any one of you? @Dalvinder Singh
 Luca Kiebel
SHOHIL SETHIA

Comment: There is one way,
Pass **this** as a parameter with the function **SaveEntity(this)**
and while you receive it in definition as **function SaveEntity(event)**
get the content by, **var content = this.value; **// This with get the textual content inside the scope of the caller element.
The above should do the job !
Then you can perform the task !
Thank you

Comment: I have tried this one brother.                                                                      
  <td><input type="button" class="newwhitebtn" id="frmCreateEntity" value="Save and New" name="saveAndNew" onclick="SaveEntity(this);"/></input> </td> But thats not working.

Comment: Hi @DeepakAhirwar
You have to work around ,
Since i do not how you are getting the data in that **<td>** element !
If you can update the question with more details,
May be better solutions will be posted !
Thank you

Comment: I am really sorry @DeepakAhirwar,
I am on Corporate system now (In office)
and cannot do something which violates Security Policy.
In case you believe i answered your query,
Please accept my answer as Solution
Thank You

Comment: I have updated the code accordingly though its not wokring.

Comment: There is an extra **"** in the very first line where you are using **id**

Comment: Also i meant about the data you want to pass,
Give a sample dummy data inside those table elements,
I i am not approaching correctly to your query update your question with sample data,
thank You

Comment: #REFRESH! Please

Comment: @DeepakAhirwar,
Please check the answer ,as i have updated it,
Also accept it as Solution if it answers your question,
Thank You

Comment: @ SHOHIL SETHIA Thank you brother

Comment: I have tried that one . but it was not working brother.

Comment: Did you check the ajax call,
Now i am sending obj object **data : obj,** in the POST call,
Did you notice that ?

Comment: by using **var obj = $(event.id).serialize();**
Hope it helps