# childNodes method of Javascript takes new line and Comment(in HTML) as an entity in array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, serialization

I have a sample of code to get child nodes of parent from child,
Below is the code,

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Sample styled page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="btn-lg pull-right">
      <!-- this is a sample comment -->
         <form>
          First name: <input type="text" name="FirstName" value="Mickey"><br>
          Last name: <input type="text" name="LastName" value="Mouse"><br>
        </form>
         <input type="button" class="primarybtn" value="Save" name="save" id="id_1" onclick="SaveEntity(this);"/>
         <form>
          Second name: <input type="text" name="FirstName" value="Mickey"><br>
          SecondLast name: <input type="text" name="LastName" value="Mouse"><br>
        </form>
         <input type="button" class="newwhitebtn" value="Save and New" name="saveAndNew" id="id_2" onclick="SaveEntity(this);"/>
    </div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  </body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
function SaveEntity(event) {
  var str = document.getElementById(event.id).parentNode.childNodes;
 var obj = document.getElementById(event.id).previousSibling.previousSibling.nodeName;
 // var ob = $(event.id).siblings();
 // obj.trim;
 // console.log(obj);
 // var str = $(obj).serialize();
 console.log(str);
 console.log(event.id);
 console.log($(obj).serialize());
    //  $.ajax({
    //      url :"/leadstatus_creation",
    //      type : "POST",
    //      contentType: "application/json",
    //      data : obj,
    //      success : function(data) {
    //      if(data != null && data !='')
    //          {
    //              $('#txtleadname').val(data);
    //          }
    //      },
    //      error : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    //          alert(textStatus);
    //          alert("Lead Name Status:"+$('#txtleadname').val());
    //      }
    //  });
 }
</script>
</html>
```

While i view the console results in browser i noticed that the **childNodes** property counts everything in childNodes like **next line("/n"), comments** so each next line in any html editor will be counted as an element in **childNodes**, 
Also attaching screenshot of the comments : [image: Screenshot]

**What are your comments on this ?
Is it a valid behavior or i am doing something fundamentally wrong ?
Also another query is that when i call the `saveAndNew` button then also the primary form is serialized and not the second one,** 
Am i missing something ?

Thanks

Regards
Shohil Sethia

Comment: `childNodes` contains all nodes including text nodes.  `children` contains only element nodes.

Comment: Also can you answer the other query in question

Comment: `document.getElementById(event.id) === event`

Comment: I agree @Andreas,
Both are same **event** itself returns the full element.
What it has anything to do here ?
Regards

Comment: You could get a collection of forms within the parent div via `$(event).parent().find('form')`, iterate them, serialize them.  `event` is just the parameter passed in by `SaveEntity(this)`, so it's the button that was clicked (and not an event).

Comment: also @James,
How will you get the previousSibling when **previousSibling** returns **text** that is **/n** (**new line** character) in console ?

Comment: I'm not suggesting you use previousSibling.

Comment: Is that the right behavior of **previousSibling** ?

Comment: Maybe explain (in the question) what your goal for SaveEntity is, before we answer questions about something you probably don't need.

Comment: No Goal in real,
Was playing around with HTML and Javascript while answering this question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45237227/button-onclick-function-is-not-saving-record-to-database/45237495?noredirect=1)

Comment: check [Element.previousElementSibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NonDocumentTypeChildNode/previousElementSibling)

Comment: @James,
Nice one James,
That does the trick to get the previous element,
But still serializing still prints the first form,
Why ?
Ideally when i click the second button it should the second form, isn't it ?

Comment: well, obj ===  the string 'form', so $(obj) will be a jquery collection of all form objects.

Comment: -1 @James
It does not get all form objects !

Comment: It really does.  I'm done now!

Comment: It does. Just check the screenshot you've added. There are two `form`s in the array (index 3 and 7). Move the buttons **in** the corresponding form and you're almost done. Just one step up in the DOM tree and you have the form.

Comment: Hi @James
Please check this codepen [Codepen](https://codepen.io/shohil06/pen/dzbMqw?editors=1111) 
and please do check the console !
Thank You (No Offense) !
Regards

Comment: Your code there is different!  Here you have obj = <something>.nodeName!  that returns "FORM".

Comment: @James
Agreed, My bad !
Thanks for the memo
Regards